# "I'd seen it happen before" -- usage of 'before' in this sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense, past-perfect

> I'd seen it happen before.

Is this sentence correct? I have mentioned the word '***before***' which gives an idea about the past event. Is it enough for the sentence to be considered as complete?

Answer (score 2):

It depends. If ***before*** means ***before now*** (present), you should say:

> I'**ve** seen it happen before.

If ***before*** means ***before then*** (past), you should say:

> I'**d** seen it happen before.

If you use this sentence in a context which explains what ***before*** refers to, then yes, your sentence can be considered as self-sufficient, but elliptic (as it omits explanatory words such as "before this particular time, this particular event.").

Comment: Based on what @fev correctly writes here, you should also understand that "before" is unnecessary to make the sentence complete - the tense itself sets the time.   So, "I'd seen it happen!" and even "I'd seen it!" are *both complete sentences* also.